# Same inputs and instructions but different delays, how?

Tags: c, embedded, delay, cpu-cycles

For TI Tiva Launchpad, I wrote a C code that takes two numbers from GPIO as inputs and then it adds the two numbers and outputs the result. Then, I connected an FPGA board to the Tiva launchpad and gave two numbers so that it multiplies them and outputs the result. I compute the time difference (propagation delay) between the output and the input with 4ns precision. Delay is in terms of microseconds so 4ns precision is good. However although I give the same input pattern at each test the resultant delay differs at each test. The code is something like that and surely accurately finding the results for all inputs.

```
int main(void) {

unsigned int z = 0;
unsigned char flag = 66, temp, select, num1, num2, res;
unsigned char num1Mem, num2Mem, num1MemOld, num2MemOld;
unsigned char resOld = 0;
unsigned int numOfOps = 0;
//Setup Clock, PORTC and RGB LEDs
SysCtlClockSet(SYSCTL_SYSDIV_8|SYSCTL_USE_PLL|SYSCTL_XTAL_16MHZ|SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN);

SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOB);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOC);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOD);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOE);
SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);

GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3|GPIO_PIN_4);            //Select input
GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7); //Inp 1 (num1)
GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3); //Inp 2 (num2)

GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);           //LEDs
GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3);//Out LS 4 bit
GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7);//Out MS 4 bit


GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_4);                       //Push Buttons
GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

select = 0;

while(1){


    num1    = (GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTC_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7)  & 0xF0) >> 4;
    num2    = (GPIOPinRead(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3)  & 0x0F);

    num1Mem = num1;
    num2Mem = num2;

    res = num1 * num2;
    break;


    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTE_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0|GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, res);
    GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4|GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_6|GPIO_PIN_7, res);


    if(res == 0)
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0x02);
    else if(res < 16)
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0x04);
    else if(res > 15)
        GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1|GPIO_PIN_2|GPIO_PIN_3, 0x08);

}

return 0;  }
```

For instance I change inputs from (0,0) to (3,5) and the resultant output changes from 0 to 15. I do that several times and each time the delay differs a little bit. I think all instructions that are executed at different instances must be perfectly the same, therefore the delay (i.e. number of cycles) must be the same but the actual case is different. Why? Is it possible or can I surely conclude that my delay results cannot be true?

Comment: kkrambo covered the answer...With the amount of code you have in the loop, just add a couple more lines of code, have a counter and write the lsbit to a gpio pin, look at that on the scope.  Any change in code of any kind can change the loop speed, but this will give a rough ballpark of the loop time.   The loop time is more relevant to you than the time from reading the operands to writing the result (unless you make the loop only do that).  go examine what is going on in the GPIO library functions you are using.  You can possibly reduce the loop time by cutting some of that code out.

Comment: Note that the execution isnt necessarily deterministic for these processors, the pipes are small so there is a potential for an effect, but the different cortex-ms have different fetch sizes, 32 or 16 bits.  If 32 then alignment can cost you or save you additional clock cycles in fetching.  there can be cache effects to if you have one.  Basically once compiled and not modified execution should be deterministic, but add any code anywhere and that and other code can change its execution time, depending.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you haven't done anything to synchronize the moment the inputs are changed with where the while loop is executing.  If you change the inputs just before the while loop reads the inputs then the outputs will change relatively quickly.  But if you change the inputs just after the while loop has read the inputs then the while loop has to finish the current iteration and loop back to the beginning and read the inputs again before you will see the output change.  So the delay that you are measuring can vary by the amount of time it takes to execute the while loop once.

Comment: Thanks, and yes you are right about that but there is another big problem because I get glitches at the output of Tiva C although the output must stay at the same value. I suspect the wire connections because I use jumper cables. And may be they cannot fully contact with the pins or the metal contact is not precise enough. I do not know.